# Importing CSV file not working properly when using drag and drop in Angular app

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

I have a functionality in my Angular app that is supposed to import a CSV file when we drag and drop it onto the box that says "Drag and drop your files here". However, the import is not working as expected. When I drag the file onto the box, it just opens the file instead of importing it. The only way to import the file is by clicking the "Drag and drop your files here" box. Any advice on how to fix this issue?

Thank you for your help!

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, Inject } from "@angular/core";
import {
  trigger,
  state,
  style,
  animate,
  transition
} from "@angular/animations";
import {
  HttpClient,
} from "@angular/common/http";
import { FileUploadModel } from './interface/file-upload.model'
import * as Papa from 'papaparse';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from "@angular/material/dialog";
import { ImporExportService } from "../../../core/services/import-export.service";
import { IUsuario } from "../../usuarios/interface/IUsuario";
import { LocalStorageService } from "src/app/core/services/local-storage.service";
import { HelpersService } from "src/app/helpers/helpers.service";
import { MessagesService } from "../../shared/services/messages.service";
import { InstructivoComponent } from "../instructivo/instructivo.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-importar',
  templateUrl: './importar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./importar.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger("fadeInOut", [
      state("in", style({ opacity: 100 })),
      transition("* => void", [animate(300, style({ opacity: 0 }))])
    ])
  ]
})
export class ImportarComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() text = "Upload";
  @Input() param = "file";
  @Input() target = "https://file.io";
  @Input() accept = "application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, text/csv";
  @Output() complete = new EventEmitter<string>();

  public files: Array<FileUploadModel> = [];
  isHovering = false;
  isHoveringContainer = false;
  nombre = '';
  validarFormatoCorrecto = false;
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ImportarComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
    private imporExport: ImporExportService,
    private localStorageService: LocalStorageService,
    private hs: HelpersService,
    private ms: MessagesService,
    public dialog: MatDialog,) {
    this.getUsuarioNombre()
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

  onDrop(event: any) {
    if (event && event.dataTransfer) {
      const files = event instanceof DragEvent ? event.dataTransfer.files : (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files;
      if (files) {
        for (let index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {
          const file = files[index];
          this.files.push({
            data: file,
            state: "in",
            inProgress: false,
            progress: 0,
            canRetry: false,
            canCancel: true
          });
          this.uploadFiles();
        }
      }
    }
  }


  onClick() {
    const fileUpload = document.getElementById(
      "fileUpload"
    ) as HTMLInputElement;
    fileUpload.onchange = () => {
      if (fileUpload && fileUpload.files) {
        for (let index = 0; index < fileUpload.files.length; index++) {
          const file = fileUpload.files[index];
          this.files.push({
            data: file,
            state: "in",
            inProgress: false,
            progress: 0,
            canRetry: false,
            canCancel: true
          });
        }
      }
      this.uploadFiles();
    };
    fileUpload.click();
  }

  cancelFile(file: FileUploadModel) {
    if (file && file.sub) {
      file.sub.unsubscribe();
    }
    this.removeFileFromArray(file);
  }

  retryFile(file: FileUploadModel) {
    this.uploadFile(file);
    file.canRetry = false;
  }

  async uploadFile(file: FileUploadModel) {
    if (file.data) {
      const csvData = await this.readCsvFile(file.data);
      const data = this.convertCsvToObject(csvData, file.data.name);
      if (this.validarFormatoCorrecto) {
        this.guardarLocalStorage(data)
        this.ms.success("El formato del documento se ha guardado con éxito");
      } else {
        this.ms.error("El formato del documento no es válido");
      }
    }
  }

  private uploadFiles() {
    const fileUpload = document.getElementById(
      "fileUpload"
    ) as HTMLInputElement;
    fileUpload.value = "";

    this.files.forEach(file => {
      this.uploadFile(file);
    });
  }

  private removeFileFromArray(file: FileUploadModel) {
    const index = this.files.indexOf(file);
    if (index > -1) {
      this.files.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  private readCsvFile(file: File): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => {
        const result = reader.result;
        if (result !== undefined && result !== null) {
          const csvData = result.toString().replace(/,/g, "");
          resolve(csvData);
        } else {
          reject(new Error("Empty file"));
        }
      };
      reader.onerror = () => {
        reject(reader.error);
      };
      reader.readAsText(file);
    });
  }



  private convertCsvToObject(csvData: string, nameFile: any): any {
    const results: any = Papa.parse(csvData, { header: true });
    results.data = this.replaceKeys(results.data)
    const newData = this.hs.filtrarObjetosVacios(results.data);
    let registrosCorrectos: any = []
    let registrosIncorrectos: any = []
    const dataProperties:any = {
      balance: {
        required: ['codigo', 'credito', 'credito', 'cuenta contable', 'debito', 'debito', 'saldo credito', 'saldo debito'],
        fieldToValidate: 'Cuenta Contable'
      },
      nomina: {
        required: ['comprobante', 'documento', 'fecha', 'cuenta', 'descripcion', 'ccosto', 'nit', 'digitoverificacion', 'nombre', 'documento referencia', 'debitos', 'creditos'],
        fieldToValidate: 'Descripcion'
      },
      equipo: {
        required: ['codigo', 'nombre', 'proveedor', 'costo'],
        fieldToValidate: 'Nombre'
      },
      tarifa: {
        required: ['codigo servicio', 'nombre servicio', 'especialidad', 'codigo tarifario', 'nombre tarifario', 'valor', 'costo equipos', 'costo insumos especiales', 'costo laboratorios', 'costo hospitalizacion', 'costo instrumentacion', 'costo rayos x'],
        fieldToValidate: 'Nombre Servicio'
      }
    };
    const dataProps = dataProperties[this.data];
    registrosCorrectos.push(...this.validarData(newData, dataProps.required, dataProps.fieldToValidate).registrosCorrectos);
    registrosIncorrectos.push(...this.validarData(newData, dataProps.required, dataProps.fieldToValidate).registrosIncorrectos);
    const objectSave = {
      fechadecarga: Date.now(), registroscargados: registrosCorrectos.length + registrosIncorrectos.length, registroscorrectos: registrosCorrectos,
      registrosincorrectos: registrosIncorrectos.length, nombrearchivo: nameFile, cargadopor: this.nombre
    }
    return objectSave
  }

  validarData(newData: any[], requiredProperties: string[], claveValidacion: string) {
    const registrosCorrectos: any = [];
    const registrosIncorrectos: any = [];
    newData = newData.sort(function(a, b) {
      const keysA = Object.keys(a).sort();
      const keysB = Object.keys(b).sort();
      for (let i = 0; i < keysA.length; i++) {
        const comparison = keysA[i].localeCompare(keysB[i]);
        if (comparison !== 0) {
          return comparison;
        }
      }
      return 0;
    });
    newData.forEach((element: any) => {
      const keys = Object.keys(element).map(key => key.toLowerCase().trim());
      const sortedKeys = keys.sort();
      const sortedRequiredProperties = requiredProperties.sort();
      if (JSON.stringify(sortedKeys.slice(0, requiredProperties.length)) === JSON.stringify(sortedRequiredProperties)) {
        this.validarFormatoCorrecto = true;   
        
        console.log();
        
        if (this.hs.validarDatos(element[claveValidacion])) {
          registrosCorrectos.push(element);
        } else {
          registrosIncorrectos.push({ ...element, [claveValidacion]: "Campo vacio" });
        }
      }
    });
    return { registrosCorrectos, registrosIncorrectos };
  }
  guardarLocalStorage(data: any) {
    let registrosActuales: any = [];
    switch (this.data) {
      case 'balance':
        registrosActuales = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("balance") || "[]");
        break;
      case 'nomina':
        registrosActuales = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("nomina") || "[]");
        break;
      case 'equipo':
        registrosActuales = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("equipo") || "[]");
        break;
      case 'tarifa':
        registrosActuales = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tarifa") || "[]");
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    let registrosActualizados: any[];
    if (registrosActuales.length === 0) {
      registrosActualizados = [data];
    } else {
      registrosActualizados = [...registrosActuales, data];
    }
    localStorage.setItem(this.data, JSON.stringify(registrosActualizados));

    this.dialogRef.close(true);
  }
  instructivo(nombreModulo: string) {
    let objetoInformativo: any = [];
    switch (nombreModulo) {
      case 'balance':
        objetoInformativo.push({
          objeto: {
            "Codigo": "01",
            "Cuenta Contable": "CAJA GENERAL",
            "DEBITO": "-",
            "CREDITO": "-",
            "Debito": "-",
            "Credito": "-",
            "SALDO DEBITO": "-",
            "SALDO CREDITO": "-"
          }, nombre: 'balance'
        })
        break;
      case 'nomina':
        objetoInformativo.push({
          objeto: {
            "Comprobante": "NOMINA",
            "Documento": "1",
            "Fecha": "15/02/2023",
            "Cuenta": "6101040602",
            "Descripcion": "PAGO DE NOMINA AL 1",
            "CCosto": "IQ05",
            "Nit": "1001525582",
            "digitoVerificacion": "3",
            "Nombre": "GIRALDO MONTOYA EID",
            "Documento Referencia ": "0",
            "Debitos": "646564",
            "Creditos": "0",
          }, nombre: 'nomina'
        })
        break;
      case 'equipo':
        objetoInformativo.push({
          objeto: {
            "Codigo": "EQ001",
            "Nombre": "Sistema de cirugía robótica",
            "Proveedor": "Proveedor de equipamiento médico ABC",
            "Costo": "123.441",
          }, nombre: 'equipo'
        })
        break;
      case 'tarifa':
        objetoInformativo.push({
          objeto: {
            "Codigo Servicio": "1",
            "Nombre Servicio": "Servicio 1",
            "Especialidad": "Especialidad 1",
            "Codigo Tarifario": "123",
            "Nombre Tarifario": "Tarifario 1",
            "Valor": "100",
            "Costo Equipos": "50",
            "Costo Insumos Especiales": "20",
            "Costo Laboratorios": "10",
            "Costo Hospitalizacion": "5",
            "Costo Instrumentacion": "8",
            "Costo Rayos X": "7"
          },
          nombre: 'tarifa'
        });
        break;


      default:
        break;
    }
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(InstructivoComponent, {
      data: objetoInformativo
    });
  }
  getUsuarioNombre() {
    const usuario: IUsuario = JSON.parse(
      this.localStorageService.getInStorage('usuario') || ''
    );
    if (!usuario) return;
    if (usuario.nombre) this.nombre = usuario.nombre;
    if (usuario.id) this.nombre = usuario.nombre;
  }

  replaceKeys(arr: any) {
    return arr.map((obj: any) => {
      const newObj: any = {};
      Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        let newKey = key.replace(/D�bitos/g, 'Debitos');
        newKey = newKey.replace(/Descripci�n/g, 'Descripcion');
        newKey = newKey.replace(/Cr�ditos/g, 'Creditos');
        newObj[newKey] = obj[key];
      });
      return newObj;
    });
  }
}
```

```css
@import 'src/styles/variables';

.upload-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  background: $color-white;
  margin: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px dashed $color-corp-ligth;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;

  p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .icon-1 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

  .title {
    margin: 0 0 4px;
    color: $color-corp-ligth;
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  .desc {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .45);
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

.hovering {
  border: 2px dashed $color-corp-ligth;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

ul,
li {
  margin: 0 20px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;

  mat-progress-bar {
    border-radius: 10px;
  }

  .file-label {
    display: inline-flex;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 5px;

    mat-icon {
      font-size: 18px;
      text-align: center;
    }


    a {
      margin-left: 4px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
}

.title {
  color: $color-corp;
}
.upload-container .icon {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.cvs-icon {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: $color-corp-ligth;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
.mat-h2{
  color: $color-corp;
}
```

```html
<mat-dialog-content>
    <h2 class="mat-h2">
        <mat-icon class="cvs-icon">description</mat-icon>
        Importación masiva de {{data}}
    </h2>
    <div mat-dialog-content>
        <div class="upload-container" #uploadzone dropzone [class.hovering]="isHovering" (mouseenter)="isHovering = true"
            (mouseleave)="isHovering = false" (dropped)="onDrop($event)" (click)="onClick()"
            >
            <p class="icon"><mat-icon style="color: #3F51B5;">cloud_upload</mat-icon></p>
            <p class="title" style="color: #3F51B5;">Arrastra y suelta tus archivos aquí</p>
            <p class="desc">Soporte para subir uno o varios archivos a la vez.</p>
        </div>
        <ul class="file-list">
            <li *ngFor="let file of files" [@fadeInOut]="file.state">
                <mat-progress-bar [value]="file.progress" color="primary"></mat-progress-bar>
                <span class="file-label">
                    {{file.data && file.data.name ? file.data.name : ''}}
                    <a title="Retry" (click)="retryFile(file)" *ngIf="file.canRetry">
                        <mat-icon>refresh</mat-icon>
                    </a>
                    <a title="Cancel" (click)="cancelFile(file)" *ngIf="file.canCancel">
                        <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
                    </a>
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" multiple="multiple" accept="{{accept}}"
            style="display:none;" />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button mat-stroked-button color="primary" (click)="instructivo(data)">
            <mat-icon class="icon-2">info</mat-icon>
            <span>Instructivo</span>
        </button>
        <button mat-stroked-button color="warn" mat-dialog-close>
            <mat-icon class="icon-2">close</mat-icon>
            <span>Cancelar</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</mat-dialog-content>
```

Comment: It's not clear from your posted code what directive you are using for the 'dropzone' attribute. Have you maybe forgotten to import the directive's module?